# How to validate status code in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

i about to make a validation status code in robot framework. i create value in json with wrong password and i want to make validation code 400 bad request with this code.

```
login_negative_user

${json}     Load JSON From File     ${CURDIR}/../json/negativeuser.json
# Set Test Variable   ${JSON_SCHEMA}  ${json}
${resp}=    POST    ${base_url}/horde/v1/auth/login     json=${json}
${data}     Convert To String       ${resp.json()}
Status Should Be    400 ${resp}
Should Be Equal As Strings      ${resp.status_code}     400
${jsondata}     evaluate    ${data}
${poselang}=    Set Variable    ${jsondata['data']['token']}

Set Global Variable     ${poselang}
log to console  Get poselang token
```

But my log is this

```
login negativeuser                                                    | FAIL |
```

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: {secret api}

am i wrong to make validation with that code? sorry i cant tell the api because it is secret

Comment: What are you getting in ${resp.status_code}? Can you log this? And what i understand from your question is, you are trying to validate response code is 400, right? If yes, let me know in comments, also if not mention what you are exactly where the error is coming (log screenshot may help us)

Comment: Please attached a log file.
To avoid errors in the POST request you should add `expected_status=any` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the argument expected status on POST Keywords like it said here : https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#POST

So replace your POST line with :

```
     ${resp}=    POST    ${base_url}/horde/v1/auth/login     json=${json}    expected_status=400
```